# Dynamically load last 6 months to a Picklist

Tags: picklist

Any suggestion for a way/best practice to load last six months to a picklist field? I need to run a query based on selection of the month.

Thanks,
Mudi

Comment: Is it a custom Vf page or standard page?

Comment: This is a VF page

Comment: These last six months will be based on any date like created date or last modified date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the method to get previous six months from the current date.

Using **addmonths** method, we can add specified number of months to a Datetime. It takes an Integer value. So,if we pass a negative value, then it gives previous month.
Using the format method, from the datetime we can get the Month String also

```
public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    for(Integer i = -6; i < 0; i++){
        String previousMonth = DateTime.now().addmonths(i).format('MMM');
        options.add(new SelectOption(previousMonth, previousMonth));
    }
    return options;
}
```

Refer [SelectOption class to dynamically create a picklist](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_selectoption.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Hi below is the code to dynamically get last 6 months with year as well-

```
//Method to get last 6 months with year
        public List<SelectOption> getLastSixMonths() {
            map for mapping month and its coresponding value
            map<integer,string> montsMap = new map<integer,string>{1=> 'Jan', 2=> 'Feb', 3=> 'March', 4=> 'April', 5=> 'May', 6=> 'June', 7=> 'July', 8=> 'Aug', 9=> 'Sep', 10=> 'Oct', 11=> 'Nov', 12=> 'Dec'};
            //pass which month is it. For now I am taking current month 
            Integer currentMonth = date.today().Month();

            //select option to display on vf page
            List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

            //for loop to dynamically add last six months
            for(integer i=(currentMonth-6); i<currentMonth; i++){
                //cheking if i < 1 then this month is of past year
                if(i<1){
                    //adding options
                    options.add(new SelectOption(montsMap.get(i+12) + ' ' + string.valueOf(date.today().year() - 1), string.valueOf(i)));
                }
                else{
                    options.add(new SelectOption(montsMap.get(i) + ' ' + string.valueOf(date.today().year()), string.valueOf(i)));
                }
            }
            //returning value
            return options;
        }
```